# How can I inspect Asp.Net WebForms session size

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, glimpse

I need to inspect the session size at certain moments. How can I achive this?

I have to tried to create a custom tab in Glimpse but the session object is always null:

```
public override object GetData(Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ITabContext context)  
{
    var result = new List<string[]> { new[] { "Object", "Number of bytes" } };

    HttpContextBase context1 = context.GetHttpContext();
    HttpSessionStateBase session = context1.Session;

    if (session != null)
    {
        long totalSessionBytes = 0;
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream m;
        foreach (var obj in session)
        {
            m = new MemoryStream();
            b.Serialize(m, obj);
            result.Add(new[] { obj.ToString(), m.Length.ToString() });
            totalSessionBytes += m.Length;
        }

        result.Add(new[] { "Total", totalSessionBytes.ToString() });
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(new[] { "Session", "Null" });
    }
    return result; 
}
```

I also tried this:

https://github.com/jasonrclark/Glimpse/commit/89416a7e7934d98a02839fc7976a288ca18f6d60

But I can't find any IGlimpsePlugin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you implemented your tab

- implementing the `Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ITab`
- inheriting from `Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.TabBase`, `Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.TabBase<T>` or `Glimpse.AspNet.Extensibility.AspNetTab`

you must make sure that you implement/override the `RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn` property so that it runs at `RuntimeEvent.BeginSessionAccess` or `RuntimeEvent.EndSessionAccess`

because by default it is `RuntimeEvent.EndRequest` which is too late for Session access

Comment: Thank you! Overriding the RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn property is the solution.